# Testing a method that returns a list which created by an inner method call inside a stream

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, junit5, spring-test

I have this method under test

```
@Override
    public List<LeaveResponseEntity> fromLeaveListToAdminHrMngLeaveList(Set<Leave> leaveList) {
        return leaveList.stream().map(this::fromLeaveToAdminHrMngLeave).toList();
    }
```

the inner method call to create this list is

```
 @Override
    public LeaveResponseEntity fromLeaveToAdminHrMngLeave(Leave leave) {
        var response= AdminHrMngLeaveResponse.builder()
                .leaveId(leave.getLeaveId())
                .leaveType(leave.getLeaveType())
                .leaveStarts(leave.getLeaveStarts())
                .leaveEnds(leave.getLeaveEnds())
                .approvedBy(null)
                .approvedOn(leave.getApprovedOn())
                .approved(leave.isApproved())
                .requestedBy(leave.getRequestedBy().getEmail())
                .build();
        try{
            response.setApprovedBy(userRepo.findById(leave.getApprovedBy()).orElseThrow().getEmail());
        }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            response.setApprovedBy(null);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

```
public class LeaveConvertersTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private EntityResponseLeaveConverterImpl leaveConverter;
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        leaveConverter = new EntityResponseLeaveConverterImpl(userRepo);
    }
@Test
    @DisplayName("Should convert a leave entity list to adminHrMng response list")
    void shouldConvertALeaveEntityListToAdminHrMngResponseList() {
        var leaveSet = Instancio.createSet(Leave.class);
        List<AdminHrMngLeaveResponse> expectedResponse = leaveSet.stream().map(leave ->
                AdminHrMngLeaveResponse.builder()
                        .leaveId(leave.getLeaveId())
                        .leaveType(leave.getLeaveType())
                        .leaveStarts(leave.getLeaveStarts())
                        .leaveEnds(leave.getLeaveEnds())
                        .approvedBy(leave.getApprovedBy().toString())
                        .approvedOn(leave.getApprovedOn())
                        .approved(leave.isApproved())
                        .requestedBy(leave.getRequestedBy().getEmail())
                        .build()
                )
                .toList();

            when(leaveConverter.fromLeaveToAdminHrMngLeave(???)).thenReturn(???);
        var response = leaveConverter.fromLeaveListToAdminHrMngLeaveList(leaveSet);
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResponse,response);
    }
```

I need to test that the expected response which I have created is equals with the actual return value of method fromLeaveListToAdminHrMngLeaveList() but I dont know how to mock the method fromLeaveToAdminHrMngLeave() behavior because this is an inner method and it calls multiple times inside the stream.

Comment: Why it isn't even a mock so how do you expect to register mock behavior on that. The mocking behavior should be on your repository. Another thing don't use `orElseThrow` instead do `userRepo.findById(leave.getApprovedBy()).map( (x) -> x.getEmail()).orElse(null);`. Throwing exceptions is expensive.

Comment: Note that your test is fully copy-pasted from your production code. If you had an error, you wouldn't catch it, because your test code does exactly what your production code does (I'm talking about the `stream().map(x => builder().....build())` part). "Inner" method doesn't really matter, since you have declared it `public` (for better or worse). It's unclear what you want to test or what you want to mock. You certainly don't want to mock the class which you are testing … which leaves you with stubbing the responses of `userRepo`.

Comment: Unrelated: funny that the `leaveLIST` variable is of type `SET`